# Nagios : How to monitor windows host from linux "by command line"?

Tags: bash, command-line, windows, nagios

I need to monitor a windows host using command line in Nagios.
As we can monitor Remote Linux host by NRPE (`check_nrpe`)using command line as :

```
/usr/local/nagios/check_nrpe -H localhost -c somecommand -t 30
```

What is the command in Linux to monitor windows host using `check_nt` plugin? I can monitor successfully by graphical method given in [Nagios Core Documentation](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/monitoring-windows.html), but I want to parse its output to some code for further processing.

I have written a simple shell script to monitor by nagios for those Linux systems.
Now I have given this script to the developer who can use this script in his QT C++ code and produced output in format suggested to him.

But now we can only monitor Linux systems as we haven't found any command yet  to append in the script, so that we can process in our code to produce output as we want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually after searching for long I found this solution:

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nt -H <host> -p <port> -v <command> -l <value>
```

So I have used this in my script as :

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nt -H $myHost -p 12489 -v CPULOAD -l 5,80,90,10,80,90
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nt -H $myHost -p 12489 -v USEDDISKSPACE -l c
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nt -H $myHost -p 12489 -v MEMUSE
```